# How to block access to php tilde files in nginx

Tags: nginx

For some reason I can't figure out how to block access to backup PHP files that get renamed PHP tilde with the tilde sign directly after the PHP

```
php~
```

example above
I tried a few variations and can't seem to work it out, and cannot find answers anywhere online.

```
location ~ /\.php~ {
      deny  all;
}
```

This doesn't work.... Can anyone show me how I can achieve that?
if you navigate to one of these files it will download it..

Answer (score 1):

You've got a fixed location set. `/.php~`, meaning only a .php~ file in the root of your site. try:

```
location ~ \.php~$
```

instead, which'll look for any file that ENDS with `.php~`.

Comment: Did you mean `location ~ \.php~$` I agree w/ the fixed location issue, but wondering if the ending ~ is also causing an issue. As you wrote it right now, the ending ~ is not being examined.

Comment: I did state I tried a few variations and I was testing in document root.
I can't seem to get it to work, and this solution doesn't work either.

Comment: @MarcB yeah I was going to edit, but wasn't sure. @oOo--STAR--oOo please let us know if this works (with the correction) - I'm curious if you need to escape the ~, like `location ~ \.php\~$`

Comment: Hey and thanks for the replies.. It doesn't with both variations.
location ~ \.php\~$ doesn't work neither does answer you posted :(

Comment: I think the tilde is completely ignored.. Is there not something we can do with mime types or have it so anything after .php is ignored?

Comment: you could tell nginx that .php~ is just a php script so it'll be executed, but that's probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Marc B is right, This is working for me:

```
location ~ \.php~$ 
{
    deny all;
}
```

provided that I add it at the end of the server block like this:

```
server 
{
   listen          80 default_server;

   index           index.html;
   root            /var/www/default;

   [... other stuff ...]

   location ~ \.php~$ 
   {
      deny all;
   }

}
```

If there are other rules that match after then it will match them..